# powermockito static and non static method chain

Tags: junit, powermock, powermockito

I want non-static method of an object returned by a static factory method to return a specific result.

After I have done this setup my test code will be calling the ConnectionFactory.getConn("ABC") indirectly through another piece of code which is being tested.

PowerMockito.when(ConnectionFactory.getConn("ABC").getCurrentStatus()).thenReturn(ConnectionStatus.CONNECTED);

I get a NPE for the above statement.

- I already have @PrepareForTest({FXAllConnectionFactory.class, ConnectionStatus.class}) at the beginning of my junit test class.

What would be the correct way of doing it?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I *guess* there is **no** point in creating a fluent/chained call for your **test** setup.

You see:

```
PowerMockito.when(ConnectionFactory.getConn("ABC").getCurrentStatus()).thenReturn(ConnectionStatus.CONNECTED);
```

is probably meant to configure **two** calls:

1. `ConnectionFactory.getConn("ABC")` and then
2. `getCurrentStatus()` on the result of that first call

And what makes you think that PowerMockito magically knows **what** should be returned by that first call to getConn()?

In other words:

1. First provide a mocked Connection object X; and configure your mocks so that getConn() returns that object
2. In addition to that, you have to configure X to return the desired value upon a call to getCurrentStatus() ... on X!

So, the answer is actually: what you want to do isn't possible. The idea is; you specify behavior such as:

```
 when A.foo() is called; then return some X
```

There is no magic power within PowerMockito to turn

```
when A.foo().bar() is called thren return Y
```

into

```
when A.foo() is called, return X; when X.bar() is called return Y
```

You have to specify that step by step.

Comment: ConnectionFactory.getConn("ABC") is already set and will return an object of correctType.

Comment: Then you might show **all** your code. If your code would be doing what you expect it to do, you would not be here, would you?